# Solrj Date request

Tags: java, date, solr, solrj

How to request by date using SolrJ?

I get as a parameter a date in this format `'01/10/2014'`. Then I convert this format to a Date object and convert the object to a UTC format. Here is a code example of what I am doing :

```
public class DateHelper {
    public static final String DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    public static final String SOLR_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";

    public static Date getDateFromString(String date, String format) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(date)) {
            try {
                return FastDateFormat.getInstance(format).parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getStringFromDate(Date date, String format) {
        if (date != null) {
            try {
                return FastDateFormat.getInstance(format).format(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return "";
    }        

    public static void main(String...args){
        Date dateFromString = DateHelper.getDateFromString('01/10/2014', DateHelper.DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT);
        String date = DateHelper.getStringFromDate(dateFromString, DateHelper.SOLR_DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

This small program displays '`2014-10-01T00:00:00Z`'. When I try to submit this date in Solr using a filter query, I receive this error from Sorl :

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Invalid Date String:'2014-10-01T00'
```

Here is my Solr query :

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery("*:*");
String date = String.format( "date:%s",dateInput);
query.addFilterQuery(date);

getSolrServer().query(solrQuery, METHOD.POST);
```

How can I solve this problem? THx for your help.

P.S : The class `FastDateFormat` is from Apache Commons Lang 3. I am using solr version 4.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the way filterQuery is created:

```java
String date = String.format( "date:%s",dateInput);
query.addFilterQuery(date);
```

That way the solr gets:

```
date:2014-10-01T00:00:00Z
```

And the exception is thrown because of the multiple `:` symbols that the Query Parser cannot parse correctly.

---

In order to fix it the special characters that are part of [Query Syntax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) should be escaped.

From the java side it can be done this way (using [ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_8_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#escapeQueryChars(java.lang.String)) from SolrJ):

```java
String date = String.format( "date:%s", ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(dateInput));
query.addFilterQuery(date);
```

Comment: Thx for your comment. I am facing another issue with solr dates. Dates are stored in UTC format by default in Solr. But when I get for a particular field date from Solr, solrj converts it to CEST timezone. You can have more details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065611/solr-formats-my-dates-from-utc-to-cest/26067269#26067269. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to query solr date field -- `Date:[YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ]`